# Difference between SQLite and PROC SQL when evaluating blank space

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sas

I am comparing two datasets to look for duplicate entries on certain columns.

I have done this first in SAS using the PROC SQL command as below(what I consider the true outcome) using the following query:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
    local AS a INNER JOIN neighbor AS b
    ON a.surname1 = b.surname2
    AND a.yob1 = b.yob2
    AND a.cob1 = b.cob2;
quit;
```

I output this result to csv  giving `output_sas.csv`

I have also done this in Python using SQLite3 using the same query:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(file_path + db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
    local AS a INNER JOIN neighbor AS b
    ON a.surname1 = b.surname2
    AND a.yob1 = b.yob2
    AND a.cob1 = b.cob2
""")
```

I output this to csv giving `output_python.csv`.

### The problem:

**The outputs should be the same but they are not**:

`output_sas.csv` contains *123 more records* than `output_python.csv`.

Within the SAS output file, there are 123 records that contain blank space `""` within the `yob1` and `yob2` columns i.e. as an example, The 123 records in the `sas_data.csv` look like this sample:

```
yob1 yob2 cob1 cob2 surname1 surname2
""     ""     1    1    xx       xx
""     ""     2    2    yy       yy
.
.
.
# Continues for 123 records
```

I find that this difference is due to the `yob1` and `yob2` columns, which, in the above 123 records contains blank space. ***These 123 record pairs are missing from the `output_python.csv` file.***

[Note: In this work, a  string of length zero corresponds to a missing value]

### In short:

The PROC SQL routine in SAS is evaluating blank space as equal i.e. **`"" == "" -> TRUE`.**

The Python SQLite code appears to be doing opposite i.e. **`"" == "" -> 
FALSE`**

This is happening even though `"" == "" -> True` in Python.

### The question:

Why is this the case and what do I need to change to match up the SQLite output to the PROC SQL output?

Note: Both routines are using the same input datasets. They are entirely equal, and I even manually amend the Python code to ensure that the columns `yob1` and `yob2` contain `""` for missing values.

### Update 1:

At the moment my SAS PROC SQL code works on uses `data1.sas7bdat`, named `local` and `data2.sas7bdat`, named `neighbor`.

To use the same dataset in Python, in SAS, I export these to csv and read in to Python.

If I do:

```
import pandas as pd
# read in
dflocal     = pd.read_csv(csv_path_local, index_col=False)
dfneighbor  = pd.read_csv(csv_path_neighbor, index_col=False)
```

Pandas converts missing values to `nan`. We can use `isnull()` to find the number of nan values in each of the columns:

```
# find null / nan values in yob1 and yob2 in each dataset
len(dflocal.loc[dflocal.yob1.isnull()])
78
len(dfneighbor.loc[dfneighbor.yob2.isnull()])
184
```

To solve the null value problem, I then explicitly convert `nan` to a string of length zero `""` by running:

```
dflocal['yob1'].fillna(value="", axis=0, inplace=True)
dfneighbor['yob2'].fillna(value="", axis=0, inplace=True)
```

We can test if the values got updated by testing a known `nan`:

```
dflocal.iloc[393].yob1
`""`
type(dflocal.iloc[393].yob1)
str
```

So they are a string of length 0.

Then read these into SQL via:

```
dflocal.to_sql('local', con=conn, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=False)
dfneighbor.to_sql('neighbor', con=conn, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Then execute the same SQLite3 code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(file_path + db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
    local AS a INNER JOIN neighbor AS b
    ON a.surname1 = b.surname2
    AND a.yob1 = b.yob2
    AND a.cob1 = b.cob2
""")
```

Even though I have made this explicit change ***I STILL*** get the same missing 123 values, even though, the null values have been changed to a string of length zero `""`.

**Potential Solution**:

However, if I instead import the dataset with the `na_filter=False` argument , this does the conversion from `null` to `""` for me.

```
dflocal     = pd.read_csv(csv_path_local, index_col=False, na_filter=False)
dfneighbor  = pd.read_csv(csv_path_neighbor, index_col=False, na_filter=False")

# find null / nan values in yob1 and yob2 in each dataset

len(dflocal.loc[dflocal.yob1.isnull()])
0
len(dfneighbor.loc[dfneighbor.yob2.isnull()])
0
```

When I import these datasets to my database and run this through the same SQL code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(file_path + db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
    local AS a INNER JOIN neighbor AS b
    ON a.surname1 = b.surname2
    AND a.yob1 = b.yob2
    AND a.cob1 = b.cob2
""")
```

***HOORAY I GET THE SAME OUTPUT AS THE SAS CODE!***

But Why does the first solution not work? I'm doing the same thing in both cases (the first doing it manually with `fill_na`, and the second using `na_filter=False`).

Comment: What are the actual values? Blank, or space, or NULL?

Comment: @CL. The actual values are a string of length zero `""`.

Comment: Regarding your last statement _"I'm doing the same thing in both cases"_, it seems pretty clear that this is not the case...

Comment: @user2877959 So I absolutely agree with you. Which is why I went in and manually checked the value and type of all cells which I had changed to `""` vs what was being used in the SAS PROC SQL code. They were indeed a string of length zero (and the same as the SAS data file, but for some reason when they get passed into the SQLite code it's a case of "Uh Wrong Answer Geoff".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are being hit by the way that SQLite3 (and most DBMS) handle null values. In SAS you can compare null values to actual values but in most DBMS systems you cannot. Thus in SAS complementary logical comparisons like (A=B) and (A ne B) will always yield one as true and the other as false. But in a DBMS when either A or B or both is NULL then both (A=B) and (A ne B) will be FALSE. A NULL value is neither less than nor greater than another value.

In SAS if both values are NULL then they are equal and it one is NULL and the other is not then they are not equal.  NULL numeric values are less than any actual number.  NULL character variables do not exist and so are just treated as a blank filled value. Note that SAS also ignores trailing blanks when comparing character variables.

What this means in practice is that you need to add extra code to handle the NULL values when querying a DBMS.

```
ON (a.surname1 = b.surname2 or (a.surname1 is null and b.surname1 is null))
AND (a.yob1 = b.yob2 or (a.yob1 is null and b.yob2 is null))
AND (a.cob1 = b.cob2 or (a.cob1 is null and b.cob2 is null))
```

Comment: It is not really correct to say `In SAS the outcome of all boolean expressions, like a.yob1 = b.yob2, have two possible results, true or false, but in most DBMS there are actually three possible results, true or false or unknown.`  What's actually happening is that a NULL value cannot be compared to any other value.  Any attempt to do so yields a `false` boolean result even if you're comparing NULL to itself.  So, while a boolean *value* can have three different values, a boolean *expression* is either true or false.

Comment: @LarryLustig Is the re-wording better?

Comment: @tom Thank you for your thorough explanation. Can I ask, why is SAS different? Were they trying to make it easier for the user?

Comment: Most likely SAS is different because it pre-dates the general adoption of SQL as the language of choice for database queries and the concept of variable length character variables.  Not sure if the design decisions were for user convenience of for the developers convenience. I like it but I am a SAS programmer and so I am used to it.  SAS also support 27 different numeric values that are treated as null by arithmetic operators.

Comment: @Tom That's really interesting. I thought I was going crazy; two queries doing the same thing getting different results based on one specific edge case. Glad to know there was actually something going on under the hood that wasn't my fault. Really great information - is there an official source where this is detailed?

Comment: @Tom: To my mind, that is a more accurate description of what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

In SAS, there isn't really a concept of null values for characters. It is more of an empty string.
However, in most SQL implementations (including SQlite, I assume), a null value and an empty string will be different.

A blank value in SAS is indeed evaluated as `"" = ""` which is `true`

In your average DBMS however, what you would call 'blank values' are often `null` values, not empty strings (`""`). **And `null=null` is not true**. You cannot compare null values with anything, including null values.

What you *could* do is change your SQlite to

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
    local AS a INNER JOIN neighbor AS b
    ON a.surname1 = b.surname2
    AND coalesce(a.yob1,'') = coalesce(b.yob2,'')
    AND a.cob1 = b.cob2
```

The coalesce function will replace `yob` with an empty string when `yob` is null.

Be aware however that, if `yob1` is null and `yob2` actually is an empty string, adding those coalesce functions will change what would have been a `null=''` condition, which is not true, to a `''=''` which is true.
If that is not what you'd want, you could also just write it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
    local AS a INNER JOIN neighbor AS b
    ON a.surname1 = b.surname2
    AND (a.yob1 = b.yob2
        OR (a.yob1 is null AND a.yob2 is null)
        )
    AND a.cob1 = b.cob2
```

Comment: Your coalesce code gives the answer I expect, without having to do any processing of the input data file. While I have used a different method (the na_filter I mentioned in my question) this is a good option. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chuck you're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer [wink wink]